# My php login script is not working properly

Tags: php, html, css

I'm a beginner to PHP and I needed a login page with a member database so I found a script from a tutorial but I don't know what's wrong.

From phpMyAdmin I created a database called "admin_logs" and then created a table called "registered_users". But when I enter a user in to the table and then try to log in from the website it says that I entered invalid credentials. So it looks like I can't get the data to the site but I don't understand why:

index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!empty($_SESSION["userId"])) {
    require_once './view/dashboard.php';
} else {
    require_once './view/login-form.php';
}
?>
```

login-action.php

```
<?php
namespace Phppot;

use \Phppot\Member;
if (! empty($_POST["login"])) {
    session_start();
    $username = filter_var($_POST["user_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $password = filter_var($_POST["password"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    require_once (__DIR__ . "./class/Member.php");

    $member = new Member();
    $isLoggedIn = $member->processLogin($username, $password);
    if (! $isLoggedIn) {
        $_SESSION["errorMessage"] = "Invalid Credentials";
    }
    header("Location: ./index.php");
    exit();
}
```

DataSource.php

```
<?php
namespace Phppot;

/**
 * Generic datasource class for handling DB operations.
 * Uses MySqli and PreparedStatements.
 *
 * @version 2.3
 */
class DataSource
{

    // PHP 7.1.0 visibility modifiers are allowed for class constants.
    // when using above 7.1.0, declare the below constants as private
    const HOST = 'localhost';

    const USERNAME = 'root';

    const PASSWORD = '';

    const DATABASENAME = 'admin_logs';

    private $conn;

    /**
     * PHP implicitly takes care of cleanup for default connection types.
     * So no need to worry about closing the connection.
     *
     * Singletons not required in PHP as there is no
     * concept of shared memory.
     * Every object lives only for a request.
     *
     * Keeping things simple and that works!
     */
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->conn = $this->getConnection();
    }

    /**
     * If connection object is needed use this method and get access to it.
     * Otherwise, use the below methods for insert / update / etc.
     *
     * @return \mysqli
     */
    public function getConnection()
    {
        $conn = new \mysqli(self::HOST, self::USERNAME, self::PASSWORD, self::DATABASENAME);

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            trigger_error("Problem with connecting to database.");
        }

        $conn->set_charset("utf8");
        return $conn;
    }

    /**
     * To get database results
     * @param string $query
     * @param string $paramType
     * @param array $paramArray
     * @return array
     */
    public function select($query, $paramType="", $paramArray=array())
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);


        if(!empty($paramType) && !empty($paramArray)) {
            $this->bindQueryParams($stmt, $paramType, $paramArray);
        }

        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $resultset[] = $row;
            }
        }

        if (! empty($resultset)) {
            return $resultset;
        }
    }

    /**
     * To insert
     * @param string $query
     * @param string $paramType
     * @param array $paramArray
     * @return int
     */
    public function insert($query, $paramType, $paramArray)
    {
        print $query;
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        $this->bindQueryParams($stmt, $paramType, $paramArray);
        $stmt->execute();
        $insertId = $stmt->insert_id;
        return $insertId;
    }

    /**
     * To execute query
     * @param string $query
     * @param string $paramType
     * @param array $paramArray
     */
    public function execute($query, $paramType="", $paramArray=array())
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        if(!empty($paramType) && !empty($paramArray)) {
            $this->bindQueryParams($stmt, $paramType="", $paramArray=array());
        }
        $stmt->execute();
    }

    /**
     * 1. Prepares parameter binding
     * 2. Bind prameters to the sql statement
     * @param string $stmt
     * @param string $paramType
     * @param array $paramArray
     */
    public function bindQueryParams($stmt, $paramType, $paramArray=array())
    {
        $paramValueReference[] = & $paramType;
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($paramArray); $i ++) {
            $paramValueReference[] = & $paramArray[$i];
        }
        call_user_func(array(

            'bind_param'
        ), $paramValueReference);
    }

    /**
     * To get database results
     * @param string $query
     * @param string $paramType
     * @param array $paramArray
     * @return array
     */
    public function numRows($query, $paramType="", $paramArray=array())
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        if(!empty($paramType) && !empty($paramArray)) {
            $this->bindQueryParams($stmt, $paramType, $paramArray);
        }

        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $recordCount = $stmt->num_rows;
        return $recordCount;
    }
}
```

member.php

```
<?php
namespace Phppot;

use \Phppot\DataSource;

class Member
{

    private $dbConn;

    private $ds;

    function __construct()
    {
        require_once "DataSource.php";
        $this->ds = new DataSource();
    }

    function getMemberById($memberId)
    {
        $query = "select * FROM registered_users WHERE id = ?";
        $paramType = "i";
        $paramArray = array($memberId);
        $memberResult = $this->ds->select($query, $paramType, $paramArray);

        return $memberResult;
    }

    public function processLogin($username, $password) {
        $passwordHash = md5($password);
        $query = "select * FROM registered_users WHERE user_name = ? AND password = ?";
        $paramType = "ss";
        $paramArray = array($username, $passwordHash);
        $memberResult = $this->ds->select($query, $paramType, $paramArray);
        if(!empty($memberResult)) {
            $_SESSION["userId"] = $memberResult[0]["id"];
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes created using PHP's [`password_hash()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), which you can then verify using [`password_verify()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Take a look at this post: [How to use password_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30279321/1839439) and learn more about [bcrypt & password hashing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/1839439)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you've simply entered a user with a plaintext password into the database. (Don't ever store plain-text passwords in a database, for a million reasons past the problem at hand.) Now, note the following line in `processLogin()` in your `member.php` file:

```
    $passwordHash = md5($password);
    $query = "select * FROM registered_users WHERE user_name = ? AND password = ?";
```

In other words: Your login system is querying the database with username and md5(password), and if there's a match, the login is considered valid. This means that you will need to generate a md5-hash of the password, and enter that into the password field of your database.

That, I presume, is why your login fails.

**I should note that MD5 isn't a particularly safe hashing method.** Nor is SHA1 an alternative these days. You may want to read the [PHP Passwords FAQ](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php). You may want to replace the `md5()` with the [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) or [crypt()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) functions, and importantly, *salt your passwords*.

Even `$salt = 'r4nd0m57r1n6'; md5($password.$salt);` is better than a straight-up `md5($password);`, should your user database ever become compromised. Though not very much better, given how computationally light-weight MD5 is to crack. (Billions of attempts per second.) At least it's not a straight-up rainbow table lookup when it's salted.